# EF Code first migrations issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I recently changed my database by adding two columns. Migration works fine but after a few hours ,the columns I added are dropped and when I restart web server the columns be added automatically again.

What is the problem?

I use ASP.NEt MVC 5, EF 6 with Code First

My context Code:

```
 static ApplicationDbContext()
    {
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(
            new System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ApplicationDbContext, Migrations.Configuration>());
    }
```

migration :

```
 internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ZagrosProject.Models.ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: _after a few hours ,the columns I added are dropped_  Weird, are you the only one who do migration to that database?

Comment: have you tried to disable automatic migrations?

Comment: @CodeNotFound Yes!

Comment: @AliBesharatinia you've your answer. Someone without the latest code source is still using EF model (without your new property (the columns you added)) and updated the database.

Comment: @igvar No ,I will try this

Comment: @CodeNotFound ,that's not possiable , i only one who developed this sofware

Comment: @igvar,  i  disable automatic migrations , The problem is still there!

Comment: @CodeNotFound i remove All migrations folder and set CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ApplicationDbContext>() in my context but  The problem is still there!